# How to get the current user id from Firebase in Flutter

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

I am trying this -

```
final Future<FirebaseUser> user = auth.currentUser();
```

but the problem is that instead of making a document by the "userid" it is making a document by the name of -

```
Instance of 'Future<FirebaseUser>'
```

This is literally my documents name right now, but I want to make it the userid specifically.

What should I do?

Comment: Do you understand how you're supposed to use Futures in dart?

Comment: Being totally honest with you..No..Actually I am new to it .. previously I was doing android java..so yeah .. NO

Comment: OK, that's something you're going to have to learn if you want to write apps with Flutter.  It's how you do asynchronous programming.  If you don't understand that, you're not going to get very far.

Comment: I know man..i am working on it..

Comment: But at least tell me the solution to this problem...

Comment: You will need to 'await' the Future to get a hold of the FirebaseUser object it will contain when the async work is done.  That FirebaseUser object will have a property for the UID of the user.  You should probably consult the Firebase Auth API docs for Flutter for more details.

Comment: You may want to read here as well to learn about asynchronous programming in Dart.  Without this knowledge, you won't get very far: https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures

Answer (score 97, accepted):

**Update (2020.09.09)**

**After firebase_auth version 0.18.0**

Few breaking updates were made in firebase_auth 0.18.0. FirebaseUser is now called User, currentUser is a getter, and currentUser is synchronous.

This makes the code for getting uid like this:

```
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

void inputData() {
  final User user = auth.currentUser;
  final uid = user.uid;
  // here you write the codes to input the data into firestore
}
```

**Before firebase_auth version 0.18.0**

uid is a property of FirebaseUser object. Since auth.currentUser() return a future, you have to await in order to get the user object like this:

```
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

Future<void> inputData() async {
  final FirebaseUser user = await auth.currentUser();
  final uid = user.uid;
  // here you write the codes to input the data into firestore
}
```

Comment: thank you! omg. new to flutter, and there's so much confusion with outdate tutorials..

Comment: @martin I hear you. The breaking changes in FlutterFire plugins are relatively recent, so it might take a while for the outdated documents to be updated...

Comment: I've been following Angela Yu's Flutter course. Despite it being so outdated, I think is quite good and I've been capable to find out how to follow every module easily, with just little tweaks here and there. But In module 15 this step was really confusing for me. Comparing Firebase deprecated code with the new code let me figure out the authentication issue. Thanks!

Comment: VS Code kept showing me an error regarding `invalid_assignment`, and to solve it I had to add `!` after `currentUser` like so: `final User user = auth.currentUser!;`

Answer (score 6):

#### Update (Null safe)

To get uid, email, and other information about the user, check if the user is signed in and then retrieve these values from the `User` class.

```dart
User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

// Check if the user is signed in
if (user != null) {
  String uid = user.uid; // <-- User ID
  String? email = user.email; // <-- Their email
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using sign in with Google than you will get this info of user.

```
final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();
void initState(){
super.initState();
 firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged
        .firstWhere((user) => user != null)
        .then((user) {
      String user_Name = user.displayName;
      String image_Url = user.photoUrl;
      String email_Id = user.email;
      String user_Uuid = user.uid; // etc
      }
       // Give the navigation animations, etc, some time to finish
    new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 2))
        .then((_) => signInWithGoogle());
        }

     Future<FirebaseUser> signInWithGoogle() async {
  // Attempt to get the currently authenticated user
  GoogleSignInAccount currentUser = _googleSignIn.currentUser;
  if (currentUser == null) {
    // Attempt to sign in without user interaction
    currentUser = await _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
  }
  if (currentUser == null) {
    // Force the user to interactively sign in
    currentUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  }

  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
      await currentUser.authentication;

  // Authenticate with firebase
  final FirebaseUser user = await firebaseAuth.signInWithGoogle(
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
  );

  assert(user != null);
  assert(!user.isAnonymous);

  return user;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to wait for the asynchronous operation to complete.

```
final FirebaseUser user = await auth.currentUser();
final userid = user.uid;
```

or you can use the then style syntax:

```
final FirebaseUser user = auth.currentUser().then((FirebaseUser user) {
  final userid = user.uid;
  // rest of the code|  do stuff
});
```

Comment: Getting Firebase currentUser is synchronous.

Comment: @DavoudBadamchi why is it Synchronous ? don't we have to wait for the response from firebase? `var user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!` is not correct? 

Comment: where to use this. I mean I can log into the mainpage . Where this peice of code i need to add. clueless please tell me

Comment: update : 

Since firebase_auth 0.18.0, the class `FirebaseUser` was changed to `User`

Answer (score 5):

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
getCurrentUser() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    final uid = user.uid;
    // Similarly we can get email as well
    //final uemail = user.email;
    print(uid);
    //print(uemail);
  }
```

Call the function getCurrentUser to get the result. For example, I used a button:

```
RaisedButton(
              onPressed: getCurrentUser,
              child: Text('Details'),
            ),
```

Comment: Update: Since firebase_auth version 0.18.0, the class `FirebaseUser` has been renamed to `User` . Therefore, if you're encountering the error message "The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked" while trying to retrieve the current user's ID using FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid.toString(), you'll need to update your code to the following:


Future<String> inputData() async {
  final User user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
  final String uid = user.uid.toString();
  return uid;
}

Answer (score 2):

This is another way of solving it:

```
Future<String> inputData() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    final String uid = user.uid.toString();
  return uid;
  }
```

it returns the `uid` as a String

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, it's still going to return a Future, no? Even though it's of type String? You'd still need to deal with it on the other end.

Comment: Since firebase_auth 0.18.0, the class `FirebaseUser` was changed to `User`

Answer (score 1):

Doing it normaly will always return

```
Instance of 'Future<FirebaseUser>'
```

Try using .then as follows

First Create function in your authservice class

```
Future<String> getCurrentUID() async{
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    final String uid = user.uid;
    return uid;
  }
```

Then call this function where you wnat this ID as Following

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void getid(String foo) {
      userID = foo;
    }

    AuthService().getCurrentUID().then((value) => getid(value));

    return Scaffold(
      ...
    );
}
```

This is most convenient method to get the ID
You can also get email and mobile no. like this.

Comment: This doesn't work. I just tried it with my code and it gives the same Instance of Future<void>.

Comment: Did you first created userID a global variable?...You can do this only by using .then()

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this.

```
     currentUser() {
         final User user = _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
         final uid = user.uid.toString();
         return uid;
      }
```

now just call `currentUser()` in your code and it will return uid of the currently logged-in user.

```
    uid=FirebaseAuthService().currentUser();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may add this into the global state before your flutter widget.

```
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final User user = auth.currentUser;
final myUid = user.uid;
```

it will make `myUid` available for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very comprehensive resource to solve all issues related to registration and login in Flutter with updated Firebase code. https://kickertech.com/login-and-register-easily-with-flutter-using-firebase/