# Persisting user on device with flutter and firebase auth

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, flutter, firebase-authentication

currently I made my first flutter app so there are things still uncertain for me. One of them is if there is a way to store the FireBaseUser in the device or construct it from information stored there, first to be able to get a new token to send http requests to my firebase backend adn second to maintain a login session after the app is closed until the user hits logout.

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the current user id from Firebase in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000825/how-to-get-the-current-user-id-from-firebase-in-flutter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Firebase plugin is smart enough to cache the user for you. You can just check the current user after the app has restarted.

Comment: Do you mean if I make a call to FireBaseAuth.getCurrentUser I should get my user even after closing the app?

Comment: That is correct. Just be sure to still call it asynchronously.

Comment: Sure! I'll try and see if it works to mark your answer as correct.