# I/flutter (12815): NoSuchMethodError: Class 'AuthResult' has no instance getter 'uid'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

i have an error to have the user's Id .

the Code is:

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

```
class UserManagement {

  Firestore db = Firestore.instance;
  var ui = db.currentUser();

  storeNewUser(user, context) {
    db.collection('/users').add({
    'email': 'thee',
    'uid': ui;
    }).then((value) {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'Home');
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firestore singleton instance doesn't have a property or method call currentUser.  You might be thinking of Firebase Authentication instead.

- https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/currentUser.html
- [How to get the current user id from Firebase in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000825/how-to-get-the-current-user-id-from-firebase-in-flutter)
- https://medium.com/@nils.backe/firebase-authentication-in-flutter-4b7aa9627046