# How to get userName from firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

How can I get details of currentUser from firebase? (filling the place holders with the data from the firebase.)

I want to get the displayName and email of `currentUser` and replace them with Placeholder1(User name), Placeholder2(login@comapany.com)

```
 new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
          accountName: new Text(
            "User name",//Placeholder 1
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15.0),
          ),
          accountEmail: new Text(
            "login@company.com", //Placeholder 2
            style: TextStyle(
                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                fontSize: 14.0,
                color: Color(0xFFDEB992)),
          ),
```

Comment: look into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54002349/11984670)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method `getUserData()`:

```
Future<AuthResult> getUserData() async{
  return await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
}
```

Then use a `FutureBuilder` to display the `email` and the `displayName`: