# How to do autologin with three diffrent userTypes in flutter and firebase?

Tags: flutter, if-statement, firebase-authentication

I have this app that do login with firebase auth and firestore to get the userType, This code is written obviously in the login page, What I want to add is autologin ASA the app runs which firebase offers with the correct userType So the first proplem how to transfer the email value to the `main.dart` page as I search in the firestore with the email to get the userType, Second proplem is that When I tried to do auto login in the login page with three different userTypes It does login but not auto login
CODE :

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then(
      (result) {
        if (result != null) {
          if (userType == 'userType1') {
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/userType1page');
          }
          if (userType == 'userType2') {
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/userType2page');
          }
          if (userType == 'userType3') {
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/userType3page');
          }
        }
```

So Here It gets the user But no auto login, what I observed that When U remove the other IFs inside the big if and do 1 Navigation It works So don't know what to do, Please Help me I asked three questions before and didn't get an answer.

> PS : NEW TO FLUTTER :)

> #FLUTTER_FOREVER

Getting user Data from firestore:

```
void getUserData() async {
    try {
      firestoreInstance
          .collection('Users')
          .document(usernameController.text)
          .get()
          .then((value) {
        setState(() {
          email = (value.data)['email'];
          password = (value.data)['password'];
          gender = (value.data)['gender'];
          username = (value.data)['username'];
          userType = (value.data)['userType'];
        });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString);
    }
  }
```

Logining in :

```
void login() async {
    final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    firebaseAuth
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text)
        .then((result) {
      {
        if (userType == 'Student') {
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/StudentsPage');
        } else if (userType == 'Teacher') {
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/TeacherPage');
        } else if (userType == 'Admin') {
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/AdminPage');
        } else {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Error'),
                content: Text(
                    'Please make sure that you have an internet connection '),
                actions: [
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text("Ok"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          );
        }
      }
```

Comment: The reason why the page is not navigating is because userType is not equal to any of the userTypes. Check the userType variable again.

Comment: userType is a local var and it is set in the firestore manually and it does navigate

Comment: I get like this kind of data from the firestore by a func and if U think the problem is there no I checked it many times and in every question like this isomeone says the same thing

Comment: ok what does it print when you put print after first if statement `if (result != null) {print(userType); if(...`

Comment: null ok but why, can't I use vars in initState

Comment: you can but obviously your variable is null... provide code how you initialise that variable and where

Comment: See editted question

Comment: But here It does get it and I use it in the login, see my editted question.

Comment: In `init()` in the received `result` is there any field that will help in deriving `userType`?  what is printed if we `print(result)`? @omardeveloper

Comment: the firebase user ' Firebase sth (Platform STH)'

Comment: @omardeveloper where in your code did you call the getUserData() function?

Comment: The login button above

Comment: I've already answered why it's null in another @omardeveloper [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62691949/why-cant-i-reach-the-variable-inside-an-initstate-in-flutter/62713513?noredirect=1#comment110923823_62713513)

Comment: Ok but now how can we make it != null

Comment: I tried everything and came out with the same conclusion I CAN'T USE VARS INSIDE INITSTATE,

Comment: @omardeveloper dont give up. What options come up when you do `result` `.` `ctrl` `space` ?  after fetching the `result` try to get user details again from firebase using user id, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54001097/13625305)

Comment: WHta does this mean 'document reference must be even......'

Comment: Where is that line  ?

Comment: It's an error happend when I tried to getUserData().

Comment: Error invalid document reference, Document reference must be an even number but Users has 1, null.

Comment: I figured it out It is because I CAN'T USE VARS IN INITSTATE!!!!!!

Comment: userNameController is a VAR !!!!!!!

Comment: I am very angry because I tried like for 2 weeks to solve this only issue and I have more issues coming

Comment: It's like a dead end'

Comment: STH weird I can use it in login() but not in another ordinary finction maybe it is not in the initState. Why I can use it in one function and not many functions ???

Comment: Check this [Getting user getails](https://gist.github.com/samsam-026/d1a90db9e35e9cbe9433c55c09fb94b8#file-splash-dart)

Comment: Do you want me to create another page which contains this code ?? but I am not using the user UID to get his details I am using his username which he entered before or else how should I find his document.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I must identify the var `userType` inside the `initState` and It worked by using the `getUserData()` function but I had a problem I can't use `usernameController` because It's a var and I didn't defined it so any idea how to get the `userType` with the document reference `usernameController` Which I can't identify X-(   'R.I.P @omardeveloper'

Comment: Hey I need to search with a var that I can identify inside the initState but not the firebase user because it needs async and initState can't take async so anything else or even better how can I identify The usernameController inside the initState. I would really appreciate it.