# Why can't I reach the variable inside an initState in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use a variable that I got from firestore by using a void finction and when I print it in the same function or another function it gets it but when I use it in an initState it gives me null HELP! the var I want is userType.
code :
getuserData form firebase:

```
void getUserData() async {
    try {
      firestoreInstance
          .collection('Users')
          .document(usernameController.text)
          .get()
          .then((value) {
        setState(() {
          email = (value.data)['email'];
          password = (value.data)['password'];
          gender = (value.data)['gender'];
          username = (value.data)['username'];
          userType = (value.data)['userType'];
        });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString);
    }
  }
```

and the initstate :

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then(
      (result) {
        if (result != null) {
          print(userType);
          print(result);
          if (userType == 'Admin') {
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/AdminPage');
          }
          if (userType == 'Student') {
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/StudentPage');
          }
          if (userType == 'Teacher') {
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/TeacherPage');
          }
        } else {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Error'),
                content: Text(
                    'Please make sure that you have an internet connection'),
                actions: [
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text("Ok"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

calling getuserdata:

```
child: Center(
                      child: Container(
                        width: 250,
                        height: 50,
                        child: FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () => {getUserData(), login()},
                          child: Text(
                            "Login",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: with the login button

Comment: Add full code snippet - nobody can see where `getUserData()` is invoked

Comment: Didn't understand.

Comment: Show full code snippet - not enought code to find your problem

Comment: there is nothing else to show.

Comment: I can't help if I can't see how and where `getUserData()` is invoked

Comment: What do U mean by invoked

Comment: To make function work you need to define it and invoke/call/run it some where in code

Comment: I call it beside the login function with a button see my editted question.

Comment: see in the login function it gets the userType text but can't in the initState

Comment: @omardeveloper what do you get when you do `print(result)`? Let me know.

Comment: I get 'Firebase Instance (Platform sth) or STH like that' I think this means that It found a logged in user

Comment: I/flutter ( 6860): FirebaseUser(Instance of 'PlatformUser')

Answer (score 0):

Let's find out why you have `userType == null` in `initState()`...

Timeline of what is going on

1. when widget state created initState() runs once before  build() is first time called
2. when build() done you have Button with onPressed callback configured
3. user clicks that Button and function getUserData() is called
4. because function is  asyncronous we have result somewhere in future
5. on result setState() is called and userType fullfilled with some data

And if no errors occured now you have userType != null

PS if you describe desired behavior - add commments, we'll try to reach result you want

Comment: This [how-to-do-autologin-with-three-diffrent-usertypes-in-flutter-and-firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62675197/how-to-do-autologin-with-three-diffrent-usertypes-in-flutter-and-firebase?noredirect=1#comment110922826_62675197) is the requirement.

Comment: U mean I should have userType != null But It is what it is and It is printed with a null val.   >:(

Comment: No, I mean in this code snippet `userType` in `initState` could not be `userType!= null`.
Always will be `null`. You need to rewrite your code