# Firebase problems getting uid within Flutter function

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I have reviewed previous answers to similar questions (eg [here](http://flutter:%20user%20Information%20is%20%5BVERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)%5D%20Unhandled%20Exception:%20NoSuchMethodError:%20Class%20%27String%27%20has%20no%20instance%20getter%20%27uid%27.%20Receiver:)) but they do not fix my issue.

I have an app in which the user records and audio snippet which is then uploaded to firebase storage.  Everything works in general, but currently there is no folder structure (so all users files would save to the same top level).  Therefore I am trying to call a user uid to create a unique user foler.  Since the user also logs in to firestore DB first  I have a specified user.uid

I have a method to call the current user

```
Future getCurrentUser() async {
final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();  # _auth is instance of FirebaseAuth
return user;
```

If I attach this to an onPressed event of a button I get the following

```
flutter: user Information is
flutter: D3sR4sKXXXXYToYQrmkkxmBNGvWq1
```

However if I call the same function within my 'stop' recording function I get a different result.

```
Stop recording () async {
// some audio commands....
var folder = _auth.getCurrentUser().toString();
print('Folder name is: ' + folder);
```

This gives me

```
flutter: folder name is: Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
```

I don't know if this is connected but I noticed  some differences in the firestore response compared to some older online tutorials.  For example, if I change my current user method as suggested in other StackOverflow examples (eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000825/how-to-get-the-current-user-id-from-firebase-in-flutter) ) to

```
Future getCurrentUser() async {
final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
return user.uid;
```

I get the following exception whether called in code or via onPressed(though the command completes),

```
flutter: user Information is
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class    'String' has no instance getter 'uid'.
Receiver: "D3sR4sKXXXXYToYQrmkkxmBNGvWq1"
```

I do not get this message when calling `user.uid` directly from the response from the users initial firestore login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
Stop recording () async {
// some audio commands....
var folder = _auth.getCurrentUser().toString();
print('Folder name is: ' + folder);
```

gives you a `Future` because the method that you created returns a Future which means it is asynchronous, that's why you use `async/await` to get the data from the future operation:

```
Future<FirebaseUser> getCurrentUser() async {
 return await _auth.currentUser();
}
```

And now when you call this method you can do the following:

```
FirebaseUser userResult = await getCurrentUser();
print(userResult.uid);
```

Basically `currentUser()` returns a [`Future<FirebaseUser>`](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/lib/src/firebase_auth.dart#L314), and the `FirebaseUser` class extends the class `UserInfo` which contains the property `uid`.

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/lib/src/user_info.dart

Comment: Thank you - I thought that because I had `await` in the `getCurrentUser` function, then I didn't need it in the `stop` call.  It seems obvious now its working.. funny the way that happens!