# Getting Current user details

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

So for the beginning I tried to get just the name of the user from Firebase and display it on the home page but it just display the widget's name.
Im using google/facebook/anonymous/email & password login methods.

Firebase instance

```
Future getCurrentUser() async {
print('done');
return _auth.currentUser;
}
```

The widget that suppose to get the user details

```
class GetCurrentUser extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_GetCurrentUserState createState() => _GetCurrentUserState();
}

class _GetCurrentUserState extends State<GetCurrentUser> {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return FutureBuilder(
  future: Provider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUser(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    print('done');
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done ) {
      return snapshot.data.displayName;
    } else {
      return Text('error');
    }
   },
  );
 }
}
```

And the String that stores the user's name

```
  String userProfile = GetCurrentUser().toString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution!

using the code of this thread's answer  [How to get the current user id from Firebase in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000825/how-to-get-the-current-user-id-from-firebase-in-flutter)

I took the void function he made and used it inside the widget I wanted to change the user name too and setState for that string

```
final FirebaseAuth _ath = FirebaseAuth.instance;

void inputData() {
final User user = _ath.currentUser;
setState(() {
  userProfile = user.displayName;
});
}
```