# how to get the current users uid from firebase in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I need to retrieve the 'uid' of the current user in my flutter app and use it as a global variable. throughout the page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the current user id from Firebase in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000825/how-to-get-the-current-user-id-from-firebase-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1):

```
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    
final User user = auth.currentUser;
final uid = user.uid;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update (2020.09.09)
After firebase_auth version 0.18.0**

Few breaking updates were made in firebase_auth 0.18.0. FirebaseUser is now called User, currentUser is a getter, and currentUser is synchronous.

This makes the code for getting uid like this:

```
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
 void inputData() {
    final User user = auth.currentUser;
    final uid = user.uid;
    // here you write the codes to input the data into firestore
}
```

Then you can create a Global class FirebaseCalls call put all the functions needed there and call it in any class you want .

Comment: I couldnt use the uid variable inside my scaffold its undefined why?