# How put a future inside initState?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, future

I created a list but I put it my future in a stream builder and it rebuilds when I scroll so I'm trying to create a future method outside in initstate that I'll call in my code.

**The problem** is I used in the docs(), informations from streamBuilder so I can't access to these, when my code is outside. How can I do ?

**This is my code**

```
Future getNewUid() async {
    CollectionReference Users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users');
    var response = await Users
        .doc(snapshot.data.docs[index]['uid']) //it doesn't take informations and it's red underlined
        .get();
        return response.data;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    var newUid = getNewUid();
    print(newUid);
    super.initState();
  }
```

**And the rest**

```
body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: BusiPosts.orderBy('time', descending: true).snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Something went wrong');
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
          {
            return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ListTile(
                            title: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                              future: newUid,
                                  builder: (BuildContext context,
                                  AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                  return Text("Something went wrong");
                                }
                                if (snapshot.hasData &&
                                    !snapshot.data!.exists) {
                                  return Text("Document does not exist");
                                }
                                if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                    ConnectionState.done) {
                                  Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                                  return GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () =>
                                        navigateToDetail(data[index]),
```

I tried to edit with no success :/

```
    CollectionReference Users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users');
    var futureResult = await Users
        .doc(snapshot.data.docs[index]['uid']) //it doesn't take informations and it's red underlined
        .get();
    return futureResult;
  }
  
  void initState() async{
    var futureResult = await myFutureFunction();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just do this:

```
Future getNewUid() async {
    CollectionReference Users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users');
    var response = await Users
        .doc(snapshot.data.docs[index]['uid']) //it doesn't take informations and it's red underlined
        .get();
    newUid = response.data;
  }

@override
  void initState() {
   getNewUid();
   super.initState();
 }
```

Comment: The problem is it doesn't take the informations from ` .doc(snapshot.data.docs[index]['uid'])` because it comes from my stream builder insided my code to have the uid of the person who posted

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check how to use asynchronous calls inside the InitState method. [Here](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/63/how-to-run-async-await-code-in-initstate-flutter-app/) is a good example on how to use the Future class, like this:

```
@override
void initState() {
  //you are not allowed to add async modifier to initState
  Future.delayed(Duration.zero,() async {
        //your async 'await' codes goes here
  });
  super.initState();
}
```

I would also check if this is the correct way to make the query.

```
var response = await Users
        .doc(snapshot.data.docs[index]['uid']) //it doesn't take informations and it's red underlined
        .get();
```

In a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000825/how-to-get-the-current-user-id-from-firebase-in-flutter) on how to get the user ID, they explain how to properly obtain the user id, and I think you can implement it to your stream builder:

```
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

void inputData() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await auth.currentUser();
    final uid = user.uid;
    // here you write the codes to input the data into firestore
  }
```

Also, in the [FlutterFire documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#realtime-changes) there’s a good example on how to read data in realtime using a StreamBuilder that could help you as well:

> ### Realtime changes
>
> FlutterFire provides support for dealing with realtime changes to
> collections and documents. A new event is provided on the initial
> request, and any subsequent changes to collection/document whenever a
> change occurs (modification, deleted or added).
>
> Both the CollectionReference & DocumentReference provide a
> `snapshots()` method which returns a Stream:
>
> ```
> Stream collectionStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots();
> Stream documentStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc('ABC123').snapshots();
> ```
>
> Once returned, you can subscribe to updates via the `listen()` method.
> The below example uses a StreamBuilder which helps automatically
> manage the streams state and disposal of the stream when it's no
> longer used within your app:
>
> ```
> class UserInformation extends StatefulWidget {
>   @override
>     _UserInformationState createState() => _UserInformationState();
> }
>
> class _UserInformationState extends State<UserInformation> {
>   final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots();
>
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
>       stream: _usersStream,
>       builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
>         if (snapshot.hasError) {
>           return Text('Something went wrong');
>         }
>
>         if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
>           return Text("Loading");
>         }
>
>         return ListView(
>           children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
>           Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
>             return ListTile(
>               title: Text(data['full_name']),
>               subtitle: Text(data['company']),
>             );
>           }).toList(),
>         );
>       },
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```