# how can one user modify a data in firestore which will not affect other user data in the app?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to flutter(and coding),I don't know if I specified the question clearly but what I want is for when a user "Follows" or "subscribe" to a product it goes to a listview but it changing the data globally in firestore, so in every user's listview has the same data subscribed. I want make it personalized for that specific user only, other can change the data too which will only affect *that specific user only,*

think of it as ecommerce cart function where every user has different thing in the cart

I did make a collection for "product" but every user getting data from same collection and it changing globally.

how can I make common subscribed data personalized for each user which will not conflict with others data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I make common subscribed data personalized for each user which will not conflict with others data.

Every Firebase user has an `id`, you can use the user's `id` and set/query documents based on that.

For example, to set the data:

```dart
.collection('bla').doc(USER_ID).set({"name": "John"})
```

and to retrieve the data based on the id:

```dart
final snapshot = await Firestore.instance
    .collection('bla')
    .doc(USER_ID)
    .get();
```

##### See also

- [How to get the current user id from Firebase in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000825/how-to-get-the-current-user-id-from-firebase-in-flutter)

Comment: This won't work. XD You are creating a doc where the user ID is the same as document ID. And then you search for a document which contains a field "user_id".

Comment: Now it's ok if you want to, you can show him a second way where he can have a field in a document and use `.where('user_id', isEqualTo: USER_ID)` query.

Comment: @Mises Thanks. This code was just an example to get the OP started. not really an in-depth answer.